# How do I get a screenshot when my app working background in swift?

Tags: ios, swift

While the application is running in the background, I need to take a screenshot and save it in the photos folder. When I try with Fastlane, it takes only the front of the application. How can I take a screenshot in the background?

Comment: you want to take a screenshot of the phone screen or of your app (which is not displayed at the moment)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is not possible. [Apple allows only few process types in the background](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/iPhone/Conceptual/iPhoneOSProgrammingGuide/BackgroundExecution/BackgroundExecution.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007072-CH4-SW4), and screenshot isn't one of them.